# Chrome Dev Tools RGBA/HSL Conversion to some new format

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I used to convert  #1c1959db to the standard rgba(255,0,0,0.3) but now it converts to some unrecognized format rgb(28 25 89 / 86%). please guide how to fix this on chrome dev tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but now it converts to some unrecognized format rgb(28 25 89 / 86%).

This is the new format as defined in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#rgb-functions)

```
rgb() = rgb( <percentage>{3} [ / <alpha-value> ]? ) |
        rgb( <number>{3} [ / <alpha-value> ]? )
<alpha-value> = <number> | <percentage>
```

You should get used to it now but you can easily convert to the old format like below:

```
 rgb(28 25 89 / 86%) ---> rgba(28,25,89,0.86)
```

All you have to do is to add the comma seperation and transform the percentage of the alpha channel to a number between `0` and `1`

Comment: Is there any way to enforce `rgba(28,25,89,0.86)` instead of ` rgb(28 25 89 / 86%)` format? Inconvenient for me to convert it manually when I copy from browser to code editor that only has support for rgba.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Shortly? IE 9 came out 10 years ago and there are a huge number of developers that still want to support that browser. This new RGB format doesn't work on browser versions from just 3 years ago. Based on that, I see people using the old RGB/RGBA format for at least the next 7 years, just to support those browser versions from 2018/2019. Chrome shouldn't be forcing-feeding me, as a developer, something that's still so relatively new. I should have the option to support older browsers if I want to.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do have to fight Chrome regularly because it automatically tries to convert my old syntax to the new one. It obviously recognizes which syntax I'm using, but still tries to force-feed me the new one. It's frustrating. The Chrome developers have made some awful decisions in the past, and this is another one.