# Google Chrome Devtool RGBA Issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've been dealing with the same issue last couple of months. I've googled the same issue but i guess no-one has address this issue before.

previously when i change the hex color transparency, for example #FFFFFF, the Chrome devtools was giving me the option of RGBA version like **RGBA(255,255,255,10%)** but now when i do the same thing the result is for 10% white color transparency ise **rgb(255 255 255 / 10%)**

As you can see the RGBA is now gone and the devtool onşy show the strange version of rgb type.

[image: rgba problem]

Does anyone issued the same problem before? And do you know how to fix it?

Comment: It's a new format of rgba which devtools started to use recently. Why is it a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Dev Tools RGBA/HSL Conversion to some new format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751185/chrome-dev-tools-rgba-hsl-conversion-to-some-new-format)

Comment: @wOxxOm this is a problem because i usually use devtools to find the perfect transparency option for a block or background. After this new changes, i'm unable to copy/paste the rgba option from the devtool. Which is really a dumb update for UI developers. Also what is the reason for this update? Can you explain to me.

Comment: @wOxxOm I empathise with his frustration, it's one I'm also having too. I understand that there's a new spec, but the new syntax doesn't work on old browsers and I don't think it's correct to punish people who are trying to make sure colors (amongst many others things) still work on older browsers.

Answer (score 4):

This was [an intentional change in DevTools](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072952). The comma-based syntax is what the spec now calls “legacy syntax”.

See https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1253242715304857601:

> In source code, stop using the old `rgb()`/`hsl()` CSS color syntax with commas.
>
> Get used to the modern comma-free CSS color syntax, supported in all modern browsers.
>
> Why? Upcoming new features such as `lab()`, `lch()`, and `color()` use the same syntax (and don’t work with commas).

Spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions

> […] for legacy reasons, an `rgba()` function also exists, with an identical grammar and behavior to `rgb()`.

Comment: That's great but when you are trying to create a comprehensive backwards compatibility css for older browsers that corporate entities still use you ended up fighting the UI of chrome.

Answer (score 2):

[image: open color picker + shift]

open chrome developer  >> open color picker + shift

Comment: Unfortunately, in yet another attempt to force a new and unsupported syntax on it's developers, Google has removed the option entirely - even in the menu you mention above - to change a value to RGBA. The only option I think I have at this point is to completely downgrade back to a version of Chrome that isn't plagued with these new awful features.