# Box-shadow property from inspect

Tags: css, sass, rgb

I need to replicate a page so I open the page with inspect mode to see how it looks in order to copy the css style.

But there is a problem with box-shadow.

The value from inspect is this:

```
box-shadow: rgb(13 13 13 / 10%) 0px 0.25rem 0.375rem 0px;
```

When I added it into my code (scss file) it throws this error:

```
SassError: Function rgb is missing argument $green.
```

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

Comment: the error is not related to the code you are showing because there is the  `$green` that we don't see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work like this:

```
box-shadow: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.1) 0px 0.25rem 0.375rem 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RGBA or a 8-digit hex color instead

```
box-shadow: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.1) 0px 0.25rem 0.375rem 0px;
```

Read more

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#rgb-functions

OR

```
box-shadow: #0d0d0d1a 0px 0.25rem 0.375rem 0px;
```

Read more

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#hex-notation

Comment: his syntax is also correct, it's the new one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63751185/8620333